# Como hago para cerrar la ventana automáticamente luego de enviar el formulario?

Tags: html, formularios

Quiero hacer que mi formulario se cierre al hacer submit y también que deberia agregarle al código para que la información que se llene en el formulario llegue a un correo específico.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Registrarse <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></center>
```

Comment: Si pudieses contextualizar un poco, ya que no se entiende que es lo que deseas cerrar propiamente tal.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, coloque mi codigo de un formulario en un menú de joomla y me aparece el formulario de contacto como una ventana emergente necesito que al hacer "submit" la ventana se cierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo esto en consideracion lo mencionado en tu comentario. Haz lo siguiente:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<center>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="cerrar()">Registrarse<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
</center>

<script>
    function cerrar() { 
        $("body").html('<div alignt="center"><h1>Enviado Exitosamente!!!</h1></div>'); //Marca nuevo contenido con un mensaje que se envio exitosamente

        setTimeout(function(){
            window.close();
        },3000); //Dejara un tiempo de 3 seg para que el usuario vea que se envio el formulario correctamente

    }
</script>
```

Esto puede ser colocado en el mismo index.html con las etiquetas `<script>`. Aunque es recomendado colocarlo en el index.js

Si lo haras de este ultimo modo, el index.js debes colocarlo del siguiente modo:

```
function cerrar() {
    window.close();
}
```

Y el html asi:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/index.js"></script>    
<center>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="cerrar()">Registrarse<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
</center>
```

Espero que pueda ser de gran ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: pues si funciona muchas gracias por la respuesta, probe con el primer código q citaste colocando el mismo js en el index.html, la otra cosa es q se cierra instantaneamente y no me aparece algun aviso como de "enviado" o "gracias por enviar la informacion" y q luego se cierre, podrias ayudarme gracias

Comment: Edito para que lo puedas ver c:

Comment: @Mabf alli edite para que puedas ver que se envio correctamente.

Comment: pues coloque el nuevo código editado y aun se cierra instantáneamente apenas hago el submit =(  y sigue sin aparecer el mensaje de exito al enviar, lo coloque todo el primer codigo en el index.html puedo enviarte el codigo completo del formulario para que lo veas, https://justpaste.it/17l1m

Comment: @Mabf Te actualizo la respuesta. Fue error mio, coloque el tiempo de espera para actualizar el body, y necesitabamos el tiempo de espera para window.close() actualice la respuesta!

Comment: <script>

function cerrar() { 
    $("body").html('<div alignt="center"><h1>Enviado Exitosamente!!!</h1></div>'); //Marca nuevo contenido con un mensaje que se envio exitosamente
  setTimeout(function(){  
  window.close();
  }, 3000); //Dejara un tiempo de 3 seg para que el usuario vea que se envio el formulario correctamente
}
</script>    Ese es el nuevo script, solo era un cambio de orden :D

Comment: PERFECTO, ahora funciona de verdad que me estas salvando la vida con esto si pudiera darte 1000 likes lo haría, ahora como podria hacer para que todo la información del formulario se enviara a un correo electronico?

Comment: @Mabf jajajajajaja eso ya entramos a hablar con el servidor. Te propongo que lo coloques en una nueva pregunta, puesto que no es algo que conozca mucho, y por otra parte, se que esto se debe enviar desde el servidor y no la capa vista :(

Comment: Bueno listo muchisimas gracias de verdad eres un genio

Comment: @Mabf gracias por tus halagos, pero simplemente es conocimiento y experiencia. Saludo y éxito en tus proyectos :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo por medio de JavaScript por ejemplo:

```
function enviaycerrar() {
    if (confirm('¿Estas seguro de enviar este formulario?')) {
       document.form1.submit();
       alert("Su formulario ha sido enviado, muchas gracias por participar");
       window.close();
    }
}

<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="javascript:enviaycerrar();"/>
```

Comment: este codigo lo agrego al index.html o al index.js ?

Comment: Puede adicionar la función al index.js. Recuerde agregar el llamado del Script en index.html 
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>